# Вопрос по функции function replace_text

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт, есть прямые ссылки на фотки в блоке контента, нужно этой функцией заменить их на вид САМИХ картинок.

Пример:

Было https://fex.net/get/435778407310/380142661
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Движок вордпрессовский, сам сайт вот - http://zhidkov-art.com/portfolio-item/artem-angelina/
Спасибо за помощь, пацаны.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Ссылка из примера - не прямая ссылка на фотку! Прямая ссылка . https://fs27.fex.net/get/435778407310/380142661/7e563428/094.jpg

Comment: Дело в том, что фалообменник по умолчанию только эти ссылки выдает, если их скопом копировать через эту функцию — https://b.radikal.ru/b06/1803/61/be8160233c98.png

, вот я и говорю, что прямая. Просто хочу автоматизацию настроить

Answer (score 1):

Используйте инструмент поиска с последующей заменой. В PHP с этой задачей вполне справится функция [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$str = '
    https://fex.net/get/435778407310/380142661 
    https://fex.net/get/435778407310/380142659
';

echo replace_text($str);

function replace_text($str) {
    return preg_replace('|(https?://\S+)|', '<img src="$1" alt=""/>', $str);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, он все ссылки заменит, которые начинаются  на "https://fex.net"? в блоке контента

Comment: @АндрейЖидков заменятся все ссылки, которые будут в переменной $str. Только ссылки на картинки должны быть правильными. Посмотрите последний комментарий под вашим вопросом.

Comment: Так в том то и дело, ссылки эти всегда разные будут, по мере того, как буду лить фотки на сайт…

Comment: Дело в том, что фалообменник по умолчанию только эти ссылки выдает, если их скопом копировать через эту функцию — https://b.radikal.ru/b06/1803/61/be8160233c98.png

, вот я и говорю

Comment: @АндрейЖидков скопируйте мой код целиком, сохраните его в отдельный файл, сохраните в переменную $str все ваши ссылки, подлежащие замене, сохраните эти изменения и запустите файл с кодом в браузере - результат наблюдайте в исходном коде.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял, а мне нужно сделать так, чтобы все ссылки, которые начинались на https://fex.net/get/… преобразовывались в изображения, как вы уже и сделали выше. Просто не пару ссылок, а все, которые начинаться на https://fex.net/get/…

Comment: @АндрейЖидков так в чём проблема? Передавайте все ваши ссылки в функцию, и они все преобразуются. Не больше, и не меньше - сколько ссылок напишете в переменной, столько и преобразуется. Если у вас массив ссылок, то просто прогоняете этот массив в цикле, и на каждой его итерации вызываете функцию replace_text() передавая на её вход текущее значение массива.

Comment: Извините, я просто вообще не в теме. Я хочу просто вставить ОДИН РАЗ функцию в functions.php и они (ссылки) должны преобразовываться на автомате всю жизнь без лишних телодвижений. Я не хочу ничего прогонять. Я просто хочу, чтобы все ссылки, которые начинаются на фэкс.нет, которые я вставляю, когда пишу пост во съемки, по нажатию кнопки «опубликовать» становились картинками. Вот и все. Извините еще раз, но вы не могли бы мне скинуть полный код, который я должен вставить в функцию. Помогите пожалуйста облегчить мне жизнь. В долгу не останусь. Спасибо.

Comment: @АндрейЖидков вы можете мне показать код вашей функции `replace_text()`, которая объявлена в файле `functions.php`? Там вообще есть эта функция? Если есть, покажите мне её код целиком, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот файл функции — https://fex.net/893967149009?fileId=385591323
А вот файл функции дочерней темы — https://fex.net/893967149009?fileId=385592836 . Очень надеюсь на Вас.

Comment: Ему в дочерней теме нужен фильтр контента, чтобы автоматически фильтровать весь вывод. Дополните, пожалуйста, свой ответ. И еще - ваша регулярка преобразует все ссылки в изображения, а ему надо только те, что ведут на fex.net.

Answer (score 0):

в общем можно вытащить url редиректа из заголовка location

```
<?php

  file_get_contents('https://fex.net/get/435778407310/380142661');
  foreach ($http_response_header as $header) {
    if(strpos($header, 'ocation')) {
      $url = str_replace('Location: ', '', $header);
    }
  }

  echo $url;
```

и использовать полученный url

Comment: Спасибо, но зачем мне вытаскивать прямые ссылки?) 
Мне нужно эти ссылки в само изображение «заковывались», как показано на скриншоте) все, которые начинаются на фэкс.нет